# Razor Syntax Date Picker sends null vlaue to Model if jquery/bootstrap/Kendo ui used

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I've a simple date picker which works fine if I do not use any of the Jquery Bootstrap and KendoUI DatePickers but that works only in Chrome. Every time I use other datepickers it just send model null value or one should say 1/01/00001 
Here is my razor syntax

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ModelManpowerRequest.RequestDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModelManpowerRequest.RequestDate, "{0:d}",
            new
            {
                @Value = DateTime.Now,
                htmlAttributes =
                    new { @class = "form-control datepicker date datecontrol" }
            })
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my model

```
[Display(Name = "Date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? RequestDate { get; set; }
```

and here is javascript

```
if ($.browser.mozilla) {
    if ($('.datepicker')[0].type != 'date') $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "1900:2015",
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            defaultDate: '1900-01-01'
        });
    });
}
```

and here is another javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // create DatePicker from input HTML element
    $(".datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like you are using too much of js libraries specially if you are using kendo and Jquery very much together than I believe you are using the reference of JQuery more than once. Please check your js Bundles and Kendo UI bundles and see the Jquery reference if added than how many time. As of my knowledge MVC KendoUI also adds a Kendo Jquery reference.

**Update**

for the new error please use this

```
       $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

This will set the date format for you

**Update 2**

now please change your razor to this

```
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RequestDate, new { type = "text", @class = "form-control datepicker" })
```

now what I've done in this one is,I've used `type = "text"` because by doing that Chrome will not take its type as `date` and will not render it according to its own behavior now this will work as it has too

Comment: Yes it was a bundle ref now as I remove I have this new error 
The specified value "03/10/2016" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: That actually is a chrome issue according to a bug which they have fixed please update your chrome browser [See Here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=405227)